# What is the closed form of this infinite sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the closed form of this infinite sum? $$ \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}(1-(1-p^{x^{2}})^{\alpha}) $$ where $$ p = \exp^{-\lambda^2} $$ and $$ 0 < p < 1, \alpha > 0, \lambda > 0, x = 0,1,2,... $$

Comment: Why do you believe there's a closed form?

Comment: Hmm.... is this meant to be some sort of stats sum?

Comment: I don't really know if its closed form exist. I just need help from you guys.

Comment: Yes, it is actually stats sum.

Comment: Is finding a closed form your ultimate goal? If this arose in some other questions, chances are only certain properties of the sum (such as convergence, asymptotic behavior, etc) are what you really need.

Comment: What if $\alpha=1, p=1/2$?

Comment: Yes, finding a closed form is my ultimate goal. @Sangchul Lee

Comment: @JCAA I will appreciate it.

Comment: As GEdgar says and Wolframalpha confirms if α=1 it is expressed in terms of Jacobi beta. But it is not elementary, so I am not sure it qualifies as a closed form.

Answer (score 2):

Case $\alpha=1$, [Jacobi theta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html)

$$
\frac{{\vartheta_3} \left( 0,p \right) +1}{2}=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty 
}{p}^{{k}^{2}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\big(1-(1-p^{k^2})^1\big)
$$
Case $\alpha=2$,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\big(1-(1-p^{k^2})^2\big)
= -\sum_{k=0}^\infty (p^2)^{k^2} + 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty p^{k^2}
=\frac{1-\vartheta_3(p^2)+2\vartheta_3(p)}{2}
$$
Keep expanding for positive integer $\alpha$.
$\alpha=3$:
$$
\frac{1+{\vartheta_3} \left( 0,p \right) -3\,{\vartheta_3}
 \left( 0,{p}^{2} \right) +3\,{\vartheta_3} \left( 0,{p}^{3}
 \right) }{2}
$$
Use binomial coefficients.